# How to print only part of output

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm kinda new to shell scripts and I'm struggling to get only the information I need from a command.

I'm executing this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
myfunction(){
   find . -name '*' -exec file {} \; | grep "image"
}
myfunction
```

Basically, what I need is the list of the names of the images on my directory and the data about their resolution, but I get a lot of data that are useless to me:

```
./image222s.jpeg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 554x554, components 3
./fruta-png.png: PNG image data, 1400 x 1501, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
./ddd.jpeg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 540x568, components 3
./images.jpeg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 452x678, components 3
```

I'd like to know how can I reduce the output to only the file name and its resolution. Something like:

```
image.jpeg: 452x678
image222.jpeg: 554x554
```

Thanks!

Comment: `-name '*'` is redundant - however you might want to add a `-type f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `identify` tool from `imagemagick`, you can pass a `-format` string to only print the needed information:

Install `imagemagick` if necessary:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Then run:

```
find . -type f -exec identify -format "%i: %P\n" {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

(or `+` instead of `\;` which will be faster but will print at the end only).

---

If you have a lot of non-image files matching your `find`, you might want to filter these first because `file` will be faster than `identify`:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'file "$1" | grep -q image' find-sh {} \; -exec identify -format '%i: %P\n' {} \;
```

Note, that `file` might filter some file formats it doesn't know about, that `identify` could do, e.g. RAW images.

Comment: I haven't timed it, but it *might* be more efficient to filter the inputs first e.g. `find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for f; do file "$f" | grep -q 'image' && identify -format "%i: %P\n" "$f"; done' sh {} +`

Comment: Depends on the relation between non-images and images. A short test on my Pictures directory says that direct identify is faster. For general content folder filtering might be better. But it might also fail for some types that identify can do, e.g. Raw images.